If two series $\sum|a_n|^2$ and $\sum|b_n|^2$ converge, does $\sum|a_n+b_n|^2$ converge?
If we take any two complex infinite series $A$ and $B$ such that the limits
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^aA_i{A_i}^*$$ and $$\lim_{a\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^aB_i{B_i}^*$$
both exists, then does the limit
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^a(A_i+B_i)(A_i+B_i)^*$$
also exist?

Of course, since $|a+b|^2\le2(|a|^2+|b|^2)$. That said, please read Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question, and avoid "no clue" questions.

Yes, $(\ell^2,||.||_2)$ is a normed space, so $||a+b||_2\le ||a||_2+||b||_2$.

Does this answer your question? Bounds / Approximation to sum of squares of sum

I got the answer.
since,
$$0\leq(|A|-|B|)^2$$
$$2|A||B|\leq|A|^2+|B|^2$$

Using triangle inequality and $GM \leq AM$
$$
\sum |A_n +B_n|^2 \leq \sum (|A_n|+|B_n|)^2 = \sum |A_n|^2 + 2|A_n||B_n| + |B_n|^2 \leq 2\sum |A_n|^2 + |B_n|^2 < +\infty
$$

This question doesn’t meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it (which encourages low-quality questions), why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards.

it didn't click to me that $$2|A_n||B_n|\leq|A_n|^2+|B_n|^2$$.
how can I miss this. it is funny.

I was able to answer my own question from the triangle inequality applied to complex numbers.
Since,
$$|A_n+B_n|\leq|A_n|+|B_n|$$
square them on both sides since both sides are positive,
$$|A_n+B_n|^2\leq|A_n|^2+|B_n|^2+2*|A_n||B_n|$$
and then apply what I got from this post,
$$0\leq(|A_n|-|B_n|)^2$$
$$2*|A_n||B_n|\leq|A_n|^2+|B_n|^2$$
so,
$$|A_n|^2+|B_n|^2+2*|A_n||B_n|\leq2*(|A_n|^2+|B_n|^2)$$
So,
$$|A_n+B_n|^2\leq2*(|A_n|^2+|B_n|^2)$$

$$\sum_{n}|a_n+b_n|^2 = \sum_{n}|a_n|^2+ \sum_{n}|b_n|^2+\sum_{n}a_n\overline{b_n} +\sum_{n}b_n\overline{a_n} $$
$$\le \sum_{n}|a_n|^2+ \sum_{n}|b_n|^2+2\sum_{n}|a_nb_n| $$
$$\le  \sum_{n}|a_n|^2+ \sum_{n}|b_n|^2+2\sqrt{\left(\sum_{n}|a_n|^2\right) \left(\sum_{n}|b_n|^2\right)}$$
and the last term converges so it is an upper bound and by moonstone convergence theorem  $\sum_{n}|a_n+b_n|^2$ converges
